# D3.js simple scatterplot points are concentrated to left side of chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

So I am currently creating a d3.js chart that has days from 1/1/2021 to 5/31/2022 on the x-axis, and number of phone activations on the y-axis. The plot points are color-differentiated by region (Americas = red, Europe = blue, Asia = yellow). Thus, the chart shows phone activations by region from 1/1/21 to 5/31/22. The input data was a csv file.

This is the output chart I got. As can be seen, the x-axis dates have a nice() method on it, so they look cleaner. The y-axis is scaled linearly, from 0 to the maximum activation recorded of around 12000. The colors are also encoded correctly, because in the original dataset, the Americas (red) had the most activations, and the plot illustrates that:
[image]

The main issue here is that the points are somehow all concentrated on the first day of the dataset, 1/1/21. I expect them to be spread apart, but somehow all the datapoints for each region (for all the days in the dataset) are clustered together on the first day.

The following is the part of my code used to generate the chart:

```
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kentahayakawa/d3js_simActivation_test/main/simActivationSampleData.csv?token=GHSAT0AAAAAABVK5Q3YVGUBL23PGSHHZBVGYVQW3GA", function(data) {
      // Add X axis
    
      var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date("2021-01-01"), new Date("2022-05-31")])
        .range([0, width]).nice();
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    
      // Add Y axis
      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 12000])
        .range([height, 0]);
      svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    
      // Color scale: give me a specie name, I return a color
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["Americas", "Europe", "Asia"])
        .range([ "red", "blue", "yellow"])
    
      // Add dots
      var myCircle = svg.append('g')
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Day); } )
          .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.Nr_of_changes); } )
          .attr("r", 8)
          .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.Customer) } )
          .style("opacity", 0.5);
```

Any help would be appreciated to make the scatterplot correct. I am assuming I am doing something with the x-axis wrong, but not sure. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is the `d.Day` value the same for each entry and not undefined?

Comment: @Mike yes, in the original csv file there is data everyday for each region. So for example, 1/1/21 would have three entries associated with it, one entry per region. Same for the rest of the days until 5/31/22. There are no undefined values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to having different types:

Here you are using dates to create the domain:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date("2021-01-01"), new Date("2022-05-31")])
```

but then here:

```
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Day); } )
```

you are parsing strings, not dates.

So, on X axis you are working with dates, and on the x position you are working with strings, so either you do work with dates or you don't.

Try the following:

`const datesDomain = data.map(i => i.day)`

note that datesRange should be already ordered, if your data is not, order the datesRange array.

then

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(datesDomain)
  .range([0, width]).nice();
```

now we are working with strings everywhere, this should work.

Another solution is to properly work with dates instead of strings, check this resource:
http://using-d3js.com/04_04_working_with_dates.html